# Is allow-top-navigation without allow-scripts safe for any iframe?

Tags: html, security, iframe

Can you tell me if doing such scheme is safe.
I got host and iframe.

Host is:

```
  <iframe sandbox="allow-top-navigation" src="http://iframe.com/i.html"></iframe>
```

and iframe is:

```
  <a href="http://example.com" target="_parent">Top</a>
```

I want to allow any website as iFrame source and allow it to redirect Host to some url BUT only on users intentional click.

Is this enough or there are some security problems i miss?

Comment: I'd also like to know whether `allow-top-navigation` is safe - i.e. if the iframe has user-generated content, could a user create a `javascript:...` link to steal other users' session data? Would `allow-top-navigation` allow this sort of injection?

Comment: The tests that I've done so far indicate that injection of JS into the top frame isn't possible, but hopefully a pro can weigh in on this.